# How to sum up sub child in laravel and sort

Tags: php, laravel

How can I sort or order the result of my query based on the `sum` of third child of the parent. Please see details below.

**What I tried**

```
$childSumTableSorter = function($parents, $column) use ($dir) {
      return ($dir == 'asc')
        ? $parents->get()->sortBy(function($query) {
              return $query->item()->inventory->sum('total');
          }) 
         : $parents->get()->sortByDesc(function($query) {
                    return $query->item()->inventory->sum('total');
                });
};
```

**Current result**

> Undefined property: Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\HasMany::$inventory

**Parent Table**

```
public function item(){
  return $this->hasMany(Item::class);
}
```

**Child table**

```
public function inventory() {
  return $this->belongsTo(Inventory::class);
}
```

**Inventory class**

```
public function receive_item(){
  return $this->hasOne(Item::class);
}
```

The inventories table has `total` column which I have to sum up and sort the parent based on the sum of the inventory.

Laravel version: **5.2**

Answer (score 0):

## Error

The *undefined property* error is due to that `item()` returns relationship query, not the result of the relationship. You should perform the query and then get your desired property from retrieved results.

## Solution

You can use nested orderBy like as below and perform summation in database layer as stated in `orderByRaw` method.

```
$childSumTableSorter = function($parents, $column) use ($dir) {
      return ($dir == 'asc')
        ? Parent::with(['item'=>function($query){
              $query->with(['inventory'=>function($query){
                  $query->orderByRaw('SUM(total) ASC');
              }]);
          }]);
        : Parent::with(['item'=>function($query){
              $query->with(['inventory'=>function($query){
                  $query->orderByRaw('SUM(total) DESC');
              }]);
          }]);
};
```

## Optimization

As said in [laravel doc for has many through relationship](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#has-many-through), your can query second relationship in a more straightforward way. In your case, you can define **inventories** method in *Parent* class.

**Parent class**

```
public function inventories(){
  return $this->hasManyThrough(Inventory::class, Item::class);
}
```

By using this method, you can get inventories right from the parent class. Something like `$parent->inventories->sum('total')`

Comment: For the first solution, I got this error:
`Undefined property: Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection::$inventory`

Comment: I already call the `Parent`, why do I need to call it again? Can we just use the `$parents` variable?

Comment: I don't know anything about your previous works, but I want to perform orderBy on a query not on the collection result.